# Making y[i] a modifiable variable in C

Tags: c

I am building a program that randomly generates a password using the ascii tabe of values and can only contain one of each char. it generates a password that is 8 char long.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 10

char Charactor(char x);
void Check(char* y);

int main()
{
char string[SIZE];//defines varriables
char* point;
point=&string[SIZE];
srand(time(NULL));
for (int i=0;i<SIZE-1;i++)//empties out the string
{
    string[i]='\0';
}
for (int i=0;i<SIZE-2;i++)//randomizes a char for each space in the string
{
    string[i]=Charactor(*point);
}
Check(point);/checks the string for duplicated values
printf("%s\n",string);//prints string on screen
}

char Charactor(char x)
{
int rnd=0;
rnd=rand()%2;//chooses char or number using ascii
if (rnd==0)
{
    rnd=rand()%10+48;
}
else
{
    rnd=rand()%26+65;
}
x=(char)rnd;
return x;
}

void Check(char* y)
{
int run=0;
for (int i=0; i<SIZE-2;i++)
{
    for (int x=0; x<SIZE-2; x++) 
    {
        if (y[i]==y[x] && run=0)
        {
            run++;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            y[i]='\0';
            y[i]=Charactor(*y);
        }
    }
}
return;
}
```

with those changes the code is running now I just have to figure out how to change the correct value so I dont have any duplication.

Comment: Post the actual error message.

Comment: You have a syntax error on this line: `Check(point);/checks the string for duplicated values`; the `/` should be `//`

Comment: Martin has described the problem. Not everything is modifiable (is an lvalue). This `(y[i]==y[x] && run)` is true or false. And you can't update true or false to be zero.

Comment: By correcting the code inside the question, you removed the actual question! Let the erroneous code be in the question, or the answers won't make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix:

`char* point =&string[0]; //Make it to point to first element`

Since your `Charactor(*point);` is really not doing anything based on `*point` and later you use `Check(point);` probably to start a scan from start of string.

And

```
 if (y[i]==y[x] && run==0)
                      ^^Use Equality check
```

You cannot modify a `boolean` outcome of `y[i]==y[x] && run` as zero.

Note :
However `if (y[i]==y[x] && (run=0) )` wouldn't have thrown this error.

Answer (score 2):

Your error seems to be that you are mistakenly setting run=0 in

```
if (y[i]==y[x] && run=0)
```

This is the part that most likely confuses your compiler. Doesn't have to do anything with Y.

Fix to:

```
if (y[i]==y[x] && run==0)
```